# Comment traduire « going ham » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, locutions, argot, registre-familier

Dans une critique<sup>1</sup> d'un *cheeseburger* enregistrée dans une voiture, j'entends une personne utiliser en anglais l'expression « going ham » dans deux contextes distincts :

> *I had to peel that [papier alu.] over real slow because the cheese is
> going... is [going ham](https://youtu.be/zGkHRa64sDY?t=161) up in here*. [J'ai dû ouvrir bien lentement l'emballage parce que le fromage là-dedans...]
>
> *I do apologize for the noise in the background 'cause [nom du
> restaurant] is right off of a main road. They're [going ham](https://youtu.be/zGkHRa64sDY?t=380) over
> here [...]* [Je m'excuse pour le bruit de fond, c'est parce que le restaurant est directement sur le bord d'une route achalandée. ...]

Ce n'est pas nécessairement une expression courante ou [connue](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58738391#58738391) ; une très brève recherche me fait voir que ça apparaît parfois dans la musique rap, chez des gens plus jeunes, chez des Afro-Américains. Les locuteurs n'emploient [peut-être](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Going%20H.A.M.) pas tous l'expression de la même manière et son origine peut faire polémique. Le mot *ham/H.A.M.* serait un adverbe [argotique](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ham) signifiant « hard as a [motherf...](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/motherfucker) » mais il s'agit d'une intensificateur référant au haut degré sans être explicitement vulgaire (« a euphemistic acronym used as a description of intensity, without explicit vulgarity », Dictionary.com).

Comment traduit/transpose-t-on la locution « going ham » dans les deux contextes évoqués (inanimé, personne) ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Reprise [musicalement](https://youtu.be/DcJFdCmN98s) vu ses qualités expressives et son originalité à mon avis ; et elle met l'accent sur l'expression justement.</sub>

Comment: Péter les plombs, péter un cable, péter une durite ....

Comment: Je viens de trouver une traduction de *go ham* dans une chanson d'Eminem par « avoir la gaule » ce qui me laisse dubitative. Pour moi *go ham* c'est  [ça](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_ham).

Comment: @None Oui mais dira-t-on que le fromage pête les plombs ? Comment/où/que va-t-on intensifier ?

Answer (score 1):

Alors, **going ham** ou **go ham** ici veut dire en anglais la même chose que going crazy. Going crazy peut vouloir dire faire un gros effort pour accomplir quelque chose, par exemple. Accomplir quelque chose en s'y donnant complètement.

C'est une expression assez nouvelle.

[another word for go ham](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/go_ham.html)

Voici une liste de synonymes en anglais:

> Contexts (slang) To put a lot of effort (into something)
> To put maximum effort into achieving something
> To work hard at a given task Verb
> To put a lot of effort (into something)

Du point de vue argotique, je dirais en français: **y aller fort ou y aller à fond**. Mais davantage dans le coup serait: [double-entendre exprès]:

> **en mettre un coup ou en fourer un bon coup** [entre autres]

> Accelérer, augmenter le rythme, travailler fort,
> avec ardeur, faire des efforts, faire un effort pour achever une
> tâche, être efficace, faire, partic

[langue française.net/bob](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/7706)

Dans le texte, il s'agit d'une description de fromage sur un cheeseburger, qui plait bien au rappeur.

La répétition du terme dans le même texte a trait au bruit de fond (venant de l'autoroute, etc.)

Comment: Attention: *double entendre exprès* risque fort d'être incompris en français. Tu peux le remplacer par *double sens intentionnel / volontaire*.